# Как сделать многоуровневый массив?

Tags: javascript

Нужен массив games, который будет содержать несколько значений: mario, snake... Каждое значение должно содержать массив попарных объектов: "A":"7","B":"2" и тд.
Вызываться примерно должно как Array[games][snake][A] - допустим это будет 7.
Ужасно объяснил конечно, извиняюсь. Благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var games = {
  mario: {A: 7, B: 2},
  snake: {A: 8, B: 3}
}

console.log(games.snake.A, games.mario.B)
```

Comment: Спасибо, завтра приму ответ)